# Table View Delegate method (didSelectRowAt) not called when row pressed

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am trying to perform a segue when the user presses a certain cell/ row on a table View. I have implemented the delegate protocol

```
extension myVC : UITableViewDelegate
```

Here is my didSelectRow function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchToOtherUser", sender: self)
}
```

There is also some extra stuff done in the previous function but when I put a breakpoint within the function, I can see that the app never goes into this function.

I have seen some of the answers previously mentioned on this topic (no user gesture is being used, and user interaction with the table view is enabled).

Does anyone have an idea on how I could fix this?

Thank you so much 
Anthony

Comment: is the `tableView` loading content ok yeah? is selection enabled? you set `tableView.delegate = self`? not really enough information here

Comment: table view content loading perfectly, selection is also enabled and No I did not set tableView.delegate = self. I completely forgot... Thank you for the reminder it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the content is loading and the selection is enabled, then things to check are:

- 1) set delegate programmatically in swift
- 2) (optional) set the tableview `delegate` to `File's Owner` in case you added a tableview to your `UIViewController` in `Storyboard` instead of creating a `UITableViewController` (which does that automatically for you).

**Check 1 - set delegate programmatically**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    ...
}
```

**Check 2 (only for TableView added to a UIViewController in Storyboard)**

In the Storyboard through `Interface Builder` you should also link the tableview's `delegate` to the `File's Owner`:

**Check 2 - Step A) **

[image]

It can be that instead of having `File's Owner` explicitly stated on the left bar, it could be that you might have to do it this way:

**Check 2 - Alternative Step A)**

[image]

and then select `delegate` like this:

**Check 2 - Step B)**

[image]

Comment: Hello denis_lor,
I am sorry I missed your answer, I never got the notification or must have missed it!
By enabling the table view delegate, it worked. I forgot to add the delegate as I added the delegate for data source via storyboard (like you did with check 2, step B). 

Silly mistake on my part and I appreciate the detailed help! Thank you very much